# Area weighted average of temperature

Tags: matlab

I have temperature data at particular longitudes and latitudes.  I want to calculate an area weighted average of the temperature in matlab.

Here is an equation used to calculate area weighted average, where the weight is obviously area. The area refers to the physical grid of interest defined by the latitudes and longitudes.

```
sum_y(sum_x( temp * area )) / sum_y(sum_x(area))
```

where `sum_x` and `sum_y` refer to the summation of the longitude and latitude dimensions.

My question is how do you sum the area in reference to longitude, then latitude and how does this translate to matlab?

Thanks
Hans

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, to sum along a specific dimension, you use:

```
sum(area,1); %sum along first dimension
sum(area,2); %sum along second dimension etc..
```

So in summary, it will look like this:

```
sum(sum(temp.*area,1),2) ./ sum(sum(area,1),2)
```